# How to initialize a struct[int] correctly with extern keyword

Tags: c++

Here's my code:

#### main.cpp

```
#include "color.h"

int main ( int argc , char **argv ) 
{
    Highlight h;
    return 0;
}
```

#### color.h

```
#ifndef HIGH_H
#define HIGH_H
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct colorPattern_t
{
    int c1 , c2;

    colorPattern_t ( int a , int b )
    {
        c1 = a; c2 = b;

        cout << "colorPattern_t() with " << c1 << " , " << c2 << endl;
    }

    void say()
    {
        cout << "say() from colorPattern_t" << endl;
    };
};

class Highlight
{
    public:
    Highlight ();
};

#endif
```

#### Now color.cpp

```
#include "color.h"

extern colorPattern_t colors[2] = 
{
    {
        1,
        2
    } ,
    {
        4,
        5
    }
};

Highlight::Highlight()
{
    for ( int i = 0 ; i < sizeof(colors) / sizeof(colorPattern_t) ; i ++ )
    {
        colors[i].say();
    }
};
```

When compiling with:

> g++ main.cpp color.cpp -o main

I see:

> color.cpp:3:31: warning: ‘colors’ initialized and declared ‘extern’
>   color.cpp:13:1: warning: extended initializer lists only available with -std=c++0x or -std=gnu++0x
>   color.cpp:13:1: warning: extended initializer lists only available with -std=c++0x or -    std=gnu++0x

I there any suggestion for my `colorPattern_t{}` initialization method? I wanted them to be mounted in my code without using `-std=c++0x` to fix the symptom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example, I don't see anything outside of `color.cpp` accessing `colors`, so there is no reason to have the `extern` on its definition.

If other files are going to have access to this global data, then declare in `colors.h` that there exists a `colors` data structure:

```
extern colorPatterns_t colors[];
```

Then in your `color.cpp` drop the `extern` and initialize it as you're doing.  The `extern` tells the compiler that the variable is declared (and possibly initialized) somewhere else.

If you do access `colors` from another file outside of `color.cpp`, the `sizeof colors` won't work, so you'll have to signal its size in some other way.  Either define the number of colors

```
 /* in colors.h */
 #define N_COLORS 2
 extern colorPatterns_t colors[];

 /* in color.cpp */
 colorPatterns_t colors[N_COLORS] = { ...
```

Or you can put in a marker in the last slot (e.g. `-1` or some other obvious illegal value).

Of course, global variables are in general evil and you should just supply a set of routines/methods in `color.c` to access / manipulate the colors structure so that you're free to change or update its implementation without affecting the rest of your code base.

Comment: Yes , another class is accessing that struct , and you're right ! i moved "extern colorPatterns_t colors[3]" to color.h and it worked. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the `extern` keyword. Non-`static` globals are `extern` by nature. It should work fine.

**Edit**: if `color.h` is included in multiple files, then it might give linker error. So it's a good practice to keep the array definition in `.cpp` file and put the `extern <array>` syntax in `.h` file.